# Chrome Extension - Opens Link in New Window from google website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a noob trying to create a easy chrome extension.  The gist - I would like for a new chrome window to open in the left side of the screen when I click a hyperlink from a specific website.  Here is as far as I can get...

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Link Opener2",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Opens.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

content.js

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  
  if (target.tagName === "A") {
    const linkToOpen = target.href;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "openLinkInNewWindow", link: linkToOpen });
  }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  console.log("Link Opener Extension Installed.");
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "openClickedLink" });
});
```

I would love some help and appreciate learning.

Result is not functioning as expected.  Link opens but in same window

Comment: Replace the entire contents of background.js with an [onMessage listener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) that calls chrome.windows.create().